Which is correct, "the implication A → B" or "the implication ‘A → B’"?
Which is correct?

The true (or false) implication A → B.
The true (or false) implication ‘A → B’.

What are the arguments for saying that it is wrong to say:

the implication A → B

and the we should say instead:

the implication ‘A → B’?

Does any academic author argue either way?

Does this answer your question? How does 'use-mention' apply to formulas?

Doesn't this depend on context of use/mention? The  implication A → B combined with A entails B. The  implication 'A → B' is a formula with three symbols.

@MauroALLEGRANZA No. I understand the use/mention distinction. The question is whether any author argued that we should write "the implication 'A → B' is true" rather than, as most authors do, "the implication A → B is true".

@Conifold "The implication 'A → B' is a formula with three symbols." Sure, and presumably, formulas, like sentences, are meant to be true or false, but this doesn't seem to say whether it is wrong or not to write without quotes or apostrophes that the implication A → B is true (or false).

"A written sentence is a string of characters. A sentence can be used by a person to express meanings, but no sentence is intrinsically meaningful. Only propositions are properly said to be true or to be false" says Corcoran. So, being pedantic, we are using rather than mentioning sentences/formulas when asserting truth and no quotes are needed. Not that I expect people to follow this pedantry. They may insert quotes simply to separate a sentence from the surrounding text, while formulas already stand out.

See Quine's textbook Mathematical Logic for a rigorous treatment of the topic.

Specifically, Quine, Mathematical Logic (Revised edition, 1981) Chapter 1, section 5, pp 27-33. Neither is correct.
